# How do I make sure that a `brew upgrade Formula` or a `brew install Formula` for a Formula I own, always runs a test?

Tags: testing, homebrew

How do I make sure that a `brew upgrade Formula` or a `brew install Formula` for a Formula I own, always runs a test, and only install or upgrade if the test passes. And if the `brew test Formula` fails, then it leaves the currently installed formula.

The goal is to make sure the installed version on a user machine always passes brew test.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `test` part of the installation or upgrade process because the artifact installation is on so called bottles (which would be generated after the install and test part), you can find examples in the [homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master).

This [homebrew-tap](https://github.com/dawidd6/homebrew-tap) repo would help you with your own tap process.